# Is it okay to store ambiguous address information in localStorage?

Tags: user-experience, forms, local-storage

I have a decently sized registration form that will require some PII data, as well as some obscure shipping information.  I am working on best UX practices for input repopulation considering the time and effort needed for the form.  I was curious if storing address info in `localStorage`, when there are no ties to a particular person, is deemed acceptable?

If page is refreshed, I want to fill back in the address info and the shipping parameters.  Email, password, name, and phone will have to be re-filled by the user for obvious reasons.

Does this sound like a safe approach?

Answer (score 1):

No. If the user is on a shared or public computer you will not be storing their PII safely.

Comment: I understand that but the client is already susceptible from the jump. Doesn't ambiguity matter here?  The reason I ask is because a major freight broker (CH Robinson) actually stores the pickup and delivery cities in localStorage as you go through their load information form.  They do not store anything about the user, but obviously feel comfortable in storing some address info.  I am assuming they do this because they know there's no way to cross-reference that information with a specific person without some form of data breach outside localStorage.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery the attorney of John.Doe.of.Summersville.Ohio@yahoo.com would like a word with you.

Comment: lol I don't want that too happen!

Comment: obviously laws vary, but I would say the principle is that you have to "take good care" of your customers data. Here your only reason for taking the risk is technical convenience. It doesn't pass the common sense test.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you risk security issues, you're also spreading state onto the client machine. Keep state in one place, and where it belongs: the server. What happens if the user gets interrupted half way through filling out the form and they need to switch devices? Establish authentication earlier in the registration process, then continue with collecting more details.

This is in line with usability best practices too. "Organizing fields into several shorter forms will make it more manageable for the user." C.f. *8. Use multi-step forms when applicable*
https://uxdesign.cc/8-ways-to-make-forms-more-user-friendly-50f3f22c708c

Comment: I appreciate the link but there's nothing in that article that pertains to repopulating inputs.  And you are pointing out the obvious - we are trying to maintain state through client refreshes.  There is zero indication of my user on the client side, and everything is done securely through htttpOnly cookies.  To clarify, we are attempting to maintain form state before a request is made to the server.  If your suggestion is to maintain partial form data in the sever, I can probably agree with that solution but your suggestion doesn't make that clear.  Maybe you can elaborate more?